# PHP: How to "force" Session_Destroy()

Tags: php, mysql, session

i'd like to know how i can force a user to "logout". Im using a php-mysqli System for User Authentification and if a "lock" a Useraccount through a mysqli query, i'd like him to logout immediately.

If there a chance to get this done or - what i thought about - do i have to check the database everytime if he uses a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, i have never coded something like this. But theres a php function 'session_id()' that might be able to help you.

Check: http://www.codeinphp.com/general/php-code-snippets/remotely-destroy-different-session-php-forced-user-signout/

To dynamically get this user session you can associate it in mysql database.

e.g:

```
User | lastLogin | lastSessionID |
-----+-----------+---------------+
1001 |  03-12-15 |daSessionValue |
```

This way you can control user sessions in your backoffice, and easily shutdown any session.

**If you dont want to store this in your database**, you can just save this information into a XML or JSON file on your server. This will require you to know how to ***serialize*** from XML/JSON into PHP.

Hope this helped in anyway!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you work with MVC or OOP you should have a parent controller or class which all controllers or class inherit. every request to your website you should check your database user status if he enabled or disabled, and this will be through function called in your parent controller constructor.

if you don't use OOP or MVC in your project you should make a one access to all your webpages like file 'index.php' in the website root, through this file you will make redirect to all your web pages, and in this file you will make your check on user status.